# Database errors in Sessions.php

Tags: php-errors, database-error

I am seeing several errors in my site logs regarding a the sessions.php file. What is this and how can I fix it?

Here are my EE details:
ExpressionEngine v2.5.2 - Build Date: 20120606 - © Copyright 2003 - 2014 EllisLab, Inc.
Script executed in 0.0993 seconds - 26 SQL queries used

And here are some example errors

**16  [error]  PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/cutandpaste.com/system167/expressionengine/libraries/Session.php on line 790**

**107  [error]  PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 90 seconds exceeded in /var/www/vhosts/cutandpaste.com/system167/codeigniter/system/core/Loader.php on line 846**

Comment: Wasn't this same question answered before here? http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/8950/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-90-seconds-exceeded-codeigniter-system

Comment: @JeremyGimbel I think this is different question. Because in topic which you show, Ian give workaround for issue, but not fix it.

Comment: @jennetcetera this error mean that your query is failed. I don't have 2.5.2 dist, so check on your site,  what query you have for 790 line in Session.php (add var_dump($query); before line 790, to see what error you have inside). I can only suggest that this is something with ip2nation module. Check if table ip2nation is fine in DB.